# Convert list<int[]> to byte[]

Tags: c#, .net

How to convert `list<int[]>` to `byte[]`?

I could use this:

```
 byte[] bytes = lista.SelectMany(BitConverter.GetBytes).ToArray();
```

But it works only for `list<int>`.  If you have few ideas - most efficient is welcome.

Comment: What's the expected behavior if one of the ints is outside the range of a byte?  For example, 1,000,000.

Comment: Got an example what the input/output data might be?

Comment: @MikeChristensen, the example that OP gave will convert each `int` to 4 bytes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
byte[] bytes =
    lista
    .SelectMany(x => x)
    .SelectMany(BitConverter.GetBytes)
    .ToArray();
```

**UPDATE:**

To convert the result to `List<int>`, you can do the following:

```
List<int> list =
    bytes
        .Select((item, index) => new {item, index})
        .GroupBy(x => x.index/4)
        .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.item).ToArray())
        .Select(x => BitConverter.ToInt32(x, 0))
        .ToList();
```

Comment: @KKKk, I am glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

```
        var listOfIntArray = new List<int[]>
        {
            new[] {1, 2, 3},
            new[] {4, 5},
            new[] {6}
        };

        var listOfBytes = new List<byte>();

        foreach (var intArray in listOfIntArray)
        {
            var listOfByteArray = intArray.Select(BitConverter.GetBytes);

            foreach (var byteArray in listOfByteArray)
            {
                listOfBytes.AddRange(byteArray);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you post part when you convert it back also? thanks in advance

Comment: @KKKk, you cannot convert it back to `List<int[]>`. Only to `List<int>`.

Comment: @YacoubMassad You're right. I think convertion it back to List<int> would solve my problem too.

Answer (score 1):

If you used the `BitConverter` on purpose you can use this (will output all 4 bytes of the integer separately)

```
byte[] buffer = testData.SelectMany(arr => arr.SelectMany(x => BitConverter.GetBytes(x))).ToArray();
```

for the sake of completeness:

```
List<int> reversed = Enumerable.Range(0, buffer.Length / 4)
                               .Select(x => BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, x * 4))
                               .ToList();
```

As in Yacoub Massad's answer this will revers in a `List<int>` instead of `List<int[]>` because by flatten the `List<int[]>` first we lose the length informationen of the arrays.

---

If you only want to cast the int values to bytes you can use this

```
byte[] buffer = testData.SelectMany(arr => arr.Select(x => (byte)x)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = lista.SelectMany(x => x.SelectMany(y => BitConverter.GetBytes(y))).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
oos.writeObject(list);
byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: sorry, I didn't mention I need c# example